# SQL Converting Compressed Binary To Text

Tags: sql, sql-server, blob

I am working in SQL Server 2019 and have a table [TBL_BlobData] that, to my knowledge, contains compressed binary versions of rich text from the front end application. The schema is below:

**[TBL_BlobData]**

| Field | Type | Example |
| --- | --- | --- |
| HostFieldName | VARCHAR(255) | DocData |
| Size | INT | 1603 |
| Type | VARCHAR(255) | HTM;LZ77 |
| Data | IMAGE | 0x1F8B080000000000000BA557DB72DB36107DEF4CFF61EB3EB49D716C59 ... |

What I would like to do, preferably all in SQL (but other methods are appreciated if this is not possible in SQL alone), is convert this data into the raw text.

I have tried converting the IMAGE to VARCHAR than DECOMPRESSING, but no luck:

```
SELECT DECOMPRESS(cast(cast([data] as varbinary(max)) as varchar(max))) 
FROM [dbo].[VW_BlobData]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Image columns have been deprecated for over a decade (SQL 2005 IIRC).  Perhaps it is time to change the table type to be varbinary(max)?

Comment: @ConorCunninghamMSFT Very fair point, but unfortunately that is out of my control and only have access to what exists in the back end of the application.

Comment: You will need to know exactly how the blob was compressed in order to decompress it. So - start asking people or reading documentation or hacking the application logic to figure out how that is accomplished. Casting a blob contains multiple instances of x00 to string is certainly the wrong path.

Comment: then temp table with varbinary(max), copy the image into it, then try decompress?

Answer (score 0):

I can use the below to pull out data from the back end of the system you are describing above.

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),DECOMPRESS(CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX),[Data])))
```